# $scope variable loses value when accessed in function

Tags: angularjs

My console.log statements are showing that $scope.selectedUser has a value during a conditional and is undefined inside my function $scope.showUserPets. How is this possible and how do I fix it?

```
var myApp = angular.module("Pets");
myApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.selectedUser = $routeParams.user;
    if ($scope.selectedUser && $scope.info) {
       console.log("Has user and doing showUserPets: " + $scope.selectedUser); // user = user1
       $scope.showUserPets();
    }

   $scope.init = function() {
      // Sets $scope.info via $http.get
   }

   $scope.showUserPets() = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < ($scope.info).length; i++) {
           console.log($scope.selectedUser + " " +  $scope.info[i].user); // $scope.selectedUser is undefined.
      }
```

Comment: In $scope.showUserPets() = function() { ...  Remove the () in the $scope.showUserPets() ... use $scope.showUserPets = function() { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $scope.showUserPets($scope.selectedUser);



   /* notice that in you code $scope.showUserPets() ... don't use () in the
   $scope variable */
    $scope.showUserPets = function(selected) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ($scope.info).length; i++) {
           console.log(selected + " " +  $scope.info[i].user); // $scope.selectedUser is undefined.
      }
```